# Do two II$_1$-factors with trivial intersection generate $B(H)$?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dim. separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.
Let $A$, $B \subset B(H)$ be II$_1$-factors such that $A \cap B = \mathbb{C}I$.

*Examples*:
(1) Take $B = A'$ then $A \cap B = \mathbb{C}I$ by definition of a factor.
(2) Take $(A' \subset B)$ an irreducible subfactor, then $A \cap B = \mathbb{C}I$ by definition of irreducibility.

Obviously $\langle A' , B' \rangle = (\mathbb{C}I)' = B(H)$.

**Question**: Is it also true that $\langle A , B \rangle = B(H)$ ?
Else, what are counterexamples?

*Remark*: It's true for the examples (1) and (2).

*Notation*: $\langle S \rangle= (S \cup S^* \cup \mathbb{C}I)  ''$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase the question as whether $A\cap B=\mathbb C$  implies $A'\cap B'=\mathbb C$.

Let $M$  be some II$_1$-factor in $B(H) $,  and let $A=M\otimes1$, $B=1\otimes M$ in $B(H\otimes H) $. Then
$$
A'=M'\otimes B(H),\ \ \ B'=B(H)\otimes M',
$$
so $A'\cap B'
=M'\otimes M'$.